# Prevent rounding when updating in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When we execute the following line the numbers are rounded. Is there a way to prevent it?

```
db.MyCollection.update({
'properties': 'XYZ'}, {
$set: {
    'coordinates':
    [-85.72394369099999, 38.36421357100005]
}}, { multi: true});
```

ends up as the following in the collection:

```
[-85.723943691,      38.3642135710001]
```

Comment: Didn't happen for me using version 4.0.2. What mongo shell version are you using?

Comment: I'm actually doing this in Robo 3T. We're using Mongo 3.4